# Why is it that $S \subset (sa^n: s \in S, n > 0)$ for any $a \in A$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Assuming A is a commutative ring with identity and S is a maximal multiplicative closed subset of A, why is it that $S \subset (sa^n: s \in S, n > 0)$ for any $a \in A$?

This is part of a bigger problem that follows quite easily from this step.

Comment: What does "for any" mean? Do you mean "for all"? In any case: the proposition is obviously FALSE if you choose $a = 0$, and it is trivially true for $a = 1$. So - please clarify what you mean.

Comment: This is the exact line from the text I was reading "Note that the smallest multiplicative submonoid containing $a \in A$ and $S$ is $(sa^n: s \in S, n>0)$"

Comment: How do you get from SMALLEST multiplicative submonoid to MAXIMAL multiplicative whatever? Then: WHO is $a$ in that line of text? It is referenced but not defined, so whoever $a$ is must have been discussed before this line.

Comment: I think it may be typo. If you allow $n \geq 0$ instead of $n >0$, then nothing goes wrong

Comment: I referenced this line from a second text and yes the first text did have a typo. Thanks!